# Command set failed.error while starting comet in glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, comet

While starting comet i am getting this error how to resolve this.
C:\glassfish3\glassfish\bin>asadmin set server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http1.http.comet-support-enabled="true remote failure: No configuration found for server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-1.http Command set failed.